# ASP.Net membership for MVC3 Project only from Web.config just like in websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership

I want to apply ASP.Net membership on areas in MVC3.0 project, but I dont want to put [Authorize] in controller. Is this possible if so then how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the security checks yourself on the call to each method by overriding OnActionExecuting in a base controller (or each one if you don't want to implement a base controller) and decide whether to allow the call or not. Just out of curiosity why not use [Authorize]?

Comment: I am just trying to prove that is there a way without using [Authorize] in controler

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement global authorization in mvc3.  You do this by first writing a global filter that overrides the default AuthorizeAttribute, then registering your custom filter in global.asax

[Check out this blog post for more details](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2011/08/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application/)